# 1 button - vs - 2 buttons

Tags: android, button

Вопрос теоретический. Есть необходимость отобразить кнопку Пуск/Пауза. Имеется два варианта развития событий.

Вариант 1: создать одну кнопку и менять текст по клику вместе с контроллером.

Вариант 2: создать две кнопки и по клику одну прятать, вторую отображать.

Какой вариант преимущественнее и почему?

Answer (score 2):

Первый вариант. Т.к. плэй/пауз это аналог чекбокса, показывающий состояние "играет-не играет" и лучше его так и реализовать. Тем более, что все известные плееры так и делают.

Comment: так а в чем выигрыш?

Comment: @morethanfish, меньше кнопок - меньше места на экране занято, меньше надо отрисовывать, UI более привычен среднему юзеру